# c# lambda + group by each 3 rows then SUM, AVG and take first row

Tags: c#, lambda, group-by

I have a list of a class Status.

```
public partial class Status
{
    public string thisStatus { get; set; }
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    //more fields
}
```

Then I want to group by my list by each 3 rows.

for example, I have 7 status : status1 ~ status7. Then it will grouped by becomes [status1-status3], [status4-status6], [status7]

```
List<Status> tmpResult = new List<Status>();
//tmpResult get data
var grouped = tmpResult
              .Select((x, index) => new { x, index })
              .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, i => i.x);
foreach (var stat in grouped)
{
    int totalDistance = stat.Select(x => x.a).Sum();
    int avgSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(stat.Select(x => x.b).Average());

    Status firstInGroup = stat.First(); //here I got an error
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type "< anonymous type: X.Models.Status x, int index>" to "X.Models.Status"

Any help would be appreciated. thx

Comment: Your code compiles fine on my machine, so there must something wrong you didn't post.

Comment: Maybe your selector clause `i => i.x` within the `.GroupBy()` is different in your original code.

Comment: Small improvement: `.Select(x => x.a).Sum()` can be replaced by `.Sum(x => x.a)`and `.Select(x => x.b).Average()` by `.Average(x => x.b)`.

Comment: @Oliver the group by part is exactly the same with my original code. Maybe I missed some dll that you used?

Comment: I just created a console application, pasted your class and logic code into it and it compiled without any error.

Comment: Just check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xCuh9A

Comment: @Oliver its kinda weird that I have that error in my machine. so in the end, i changed the logic to take the first element. thx for your effort in this.